# Access a website when tapping an image in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, url, web, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am making an app using cocos2d for using images to display data.
I want to make the display image as a "link".
So, when the user taps the image, it opens up a particular website.
I am using cocos2d and objective-c for the first time.
I don't know how to proceed with this

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)createImageButton
{
        CCSprite *image_1   = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image_1.png"];
        CCSprite *image_2   = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image_2.png"];

        CCMenuItemSprite *imageBtn = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite: image_1
                                       selectedSprite:image_2
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(imageBtnPress:) ];

        imageBtn.position = ccp(width*0.5f, height*0.5f);


        CCMenu  *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: imageBtn, nil];
        menu.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
        [self addChild: menu z:100];
}

-(void) imageBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    //here open website link
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
}
```